# v-bind:style with array of styles

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue with a v-for loop to create spans. The following is successful with one style using bootstrap4's background-color:

```
<span v-for="(group, index) in item.primary" 
      :key="index" 
      :class="'badge'" 
      :style="{`background-color: ${tagsText[group].color}`">
      {{ group }}
</span>

<script>
    export default {
     data () {
      return {
        tagsText: {
         calling_spirits: {
           color: '#800000',
           text: 'light'
           }
         }};
     }
    };
</script>
```

I want to add a second styling (for text colour) but can't get it to work. With the span style changed to the following, I get no errors and no styling.

```
:style="`background-color: ${tagsText[group].color}`, `text-light`">
```

Same with:

```
:style="`background-color: ${tagsText[group].color}`, `text-${tagsText[group].text}`">
```

Comment: It looks like the text color property you're trying to assign is actually a class. `text-light` in itself is not a valid CSS style property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend reading https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html and understanding object and array syntaxes. Like [Shekhar Chikara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1455421/shekhar-chikara) says you're mixing inline styles with classes. Your template should be something like this, I believe:

```html
<span
  v-for="(group, index) in item.primary" 
  :key="index" 
  :class="`badge text-${tagsText[group].text}`"
  :style="{ backgroundColor: tagsText[group].color }">
  {{ group }}
</span>
```

ie, `text-light` is a css class. You should add to `class` attribute of `span` element.

Comment: Thank you, you are both correct. Before you guys pointed this oversight out, I implemented an alternate solution that includes a :id(group) and defines styling in CSS. Thanks I will accept and also write the alternative soon.